# Are there any user interfaces for accessing Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

My application uses Azure Service Bus to exchange messages and everything's working fine most of the time. The odd message is being generated that isn't processed correctly and, by design, these are going into the DeadLetterQueue.

However, in order to debug why those messages failed, I need to peek/receive those messages on my development machine and I think I will also need to tweak those messages and put them back on the queue.

The only tool to help with this job that I've found is [Service Bus Explorer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a), which is a good start, but doesn't do everything I would like.

Are there any other good applications to debug / manage the Azure Service Bus?

#### Update

Service Bus Explorer has since had a major update that I've not investigated properly - anyone coming across this question should check that out first!

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2012 has service bus management capability. Not sure if it has all the features you're looking for but you can give it a try.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned that I've seen that as well - I can't see a way of only receiving dead messages with this interface (but there's a firewall problem with it for me anyway).

Comment: New information: some of this functionality is apparently on the Azure product list so we should see it soon.